# 2013 Surveys - Want to restrict viewing answers, how to still have admin access to data?

Tags: 2013, survey

So I have built a survey and the idea is that people can respond but cannot see other people's responses.

How do I still have someone able to view all responses as an admin? Site Admin does not seem to allow viewing anything but their own responses.

Answer (score 0):

On the survey start page, Click 'Settings' --> select 'Survey settings' then on the next page click the 'Advanced Settings' link and on the next page select the options 'Read responses that were created by the user' and also 'Create responses and edit responses that were created by the user'

[image]